# Created a form using actions in Foundry and connected it to a workshop, but the input isn't getting sent to the backing dataset, how do I troubleshoot

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I created a form using actions. Called the action in workshop, but when I input the form, the information won't get saved in the backing dataset of the object type.

Tried changing dataset, checking action and object type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User edits are not stored in the backing dataset.

They are stored in the writeback dataset that is configured in the object type if your object type is in Object Storage v1.

If you are using Object Storage v2, then you will have to configure materialization in the object type configuration.

You can refer the below documentation:

https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/object-edits/materializations/index.html